# Задать цвет фона для кнопки через javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите задать цвет фона для кнопки через javascript

```
<input type="submit" id="submitfly" value="отправить">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById("submitfly");
el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: можно обернуть в объект я думаю и засунуть этот объект в config.js 
как здесь https://jsfiddle.net/d8a1zsdb/

Comment: или хотя бы так только https://jsfiddle.net/d8a1zsdb только объект засунуть в config.js и ссылку на него в конец?